# SQL table join with multiple duplicates - returning count less than X within a date range

Tags: mysql

My head is spinning. I have been struggling for the past two days to come up with a MySQL query that joins two tables. I've run into several complications.

The first table, we'll call it `log`, has a log of people which have "signed in". Each entry is timestamped with datetime. It consists of a `student_id` and `timestamp`. It looks something like this

```
  -------------------------------------
  | student_id  | timestamp           |
  | 1234        | 2014-02-26 21:50:27 |
  | 2345        | 2014-02-26 21:54:54 |
  | 1234        | 2014-03-03 19:18:18 |
  | .....etc.                         |
  -------------------------------------
```

My second table, we'll call it `students` has the information on each student.

```
  --------------------------------------------------------
  | student_id  | name                | homeroom         |
  | 1234        | Charles Reinmuth    | Swatosh          |
  | 2345        | Kathryn Mo          | Green            |
  | 6789        | Emily Salt          | Clayborne        |
  | .....etc.                                            |
  --------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to return students, within a certain datetime range, that have fewer than X entries in the `log`. INCLUDING students with no entries within that datetime range. My current query works well. But only returns students with >0 entries in the log. I've tried `LEFT OUTER` and `RIGHT OUTER` but to no avail. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT students.name, students.homeroom, COUNT(1) AS cnt 
FROM students 
INNER JOIN log ON log.student_id = students.student_id 
WHERE log.`datetime` between '2014-02-25 00:00:00' and '2014-03-04 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY log.student_id HAVING COUNT(1) < 3
```

This will return, in the case of the example above:

```
  --------------------------------------------------
  | Name             | Homeroom         | Count    |
  | Charles Reinmuth | Swatosh          | 2        |
  | Kathryn Mo       | Green            | 1        |
  | .....etc.                                      |
  --------------------------------------------------
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
  --------------------------------------------------
  | Name             | Homeroom         | Count    |
  | Charles Reinmuth | Swatosh          | 2        |
  | Kathryn Mo       | Green            | 1        |
  | Emily Salt       | Clayborne        | 0        |
  | .....etc.                                      |
  --------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if you want to return students with no logins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rows with no matches in the second table, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT students.name, students.homeroom, COUNT(log.student_id) AS cnt 
FROM students 
LEFT JOIN log 
    ON log.student_id = students.student_id 
        AND log.`datetime` between '2014-02-25 00:00:00' and '2014-03-04 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY students.student_id
HAVING cnt < 3
```

Note the other changes I made:

- `COUNT(log.student_id)` - Otherwise, you'll count the row from the `students` table, even though there's no `log` row. `COUNT(column)` doesn't count null values, which is what you get when there's no match.
- The `log.datetime` test must be moved into the `ON` clause, because it will be `NULL` for students with no rows in `log`.
- I changed the `HAVING` clause to use the `cnt` alias, to avoid having to repeat `COUNT(log.student_id)`.

Comment: Moving `log.datetime` to the `ON` clause was the part I was missing. THANK YOU SO MUCH! You are incredible.